# How do I open a c++ project folder in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a c++ project with lots of folders and compiles to lots of different executables, I want to open the entire thing in visual studio and have it keep the folder structure of my project.

Right now when try to create a new VS project and import my non-VS c++ project, it automatically puts *all* header files in one folder and source files in another completely ignoring my folder structure. How do I get visual studio to keep my folder structure when opening a C++ project that's not created with visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can select the project and then select `Show All Files` from `Solution Explorer`  tool bar. You can then Include and Exclude files/folders from the project directory.

Comment: I want to do the opposite of that :P Basically in the same way that when you open a folder as a web project, it keeps files in it's original folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the folder you want them to be in in **Solution Explorer**, select Add->Existing Item...

This skips a lot of the nice updating/verifying performed when you create a new VS project from existing files but is one way to structure a lot of files.

I'd prefer to manage them within **Solution Explorer** but I feel this is so obvious you either dissapprove or have a prohibitively large number of files to hunt and sort them with the small **Solution Explorer** window pane.

Comment: Yeah, there are about 150 cpp files and 100 header files, but each folder/subfolder only has 10 or so of mixed .h/.cpp files which is much more manageable. VS just puts them in a header file folder and a source file folder which makes things really heard to find.

Comment: @Charles, you have my alternative, import/add them piecemeal. 250 folder/files is too many to sort yourself with the limited __Solution Explorer__

Comment: Hello @John could you take a look to this question please? I've some difficulties to open the project because there isn't a sln or other files recognized by VS as a project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77140823/option-build-solution-in-visual-studio-2022-doesnt-appear?noredirect=1#comment135998364_77140823