# Option Build Solution in Visual Studio 2022 doesn't appear

Tags: visual-studio

I'm searching the option "Build the solution" in Visual Studio 2022:

[image]

but the only available option is "Run code analysis on solution":

[image]

Could you tell me how to show the build option please?

---

EDIT: I opened the folder and now the Build button disappeared from the toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Is there a build running already (or in the background)? When that happens, the only *active* command I see on the "Build" menu is "Run Code Analysis...".

Comment: Hello @AdrianMole I turned on the PC, then I opened the file hideMe.cpp with VS, and that's all. I took the file from: https://github.com/reversinghub/hide-and-seek

Comment: Well, if you just opened a ".cpp" file, then  there's no project to build. You'll need to create a project, then add that C++ source to it.

Comment: @AdrianMole thank you for the suggestion; I tried and now the button Build disappeared from the toolbar (see the figure please).

Comment: @AdrianMole in general a project has a sln file; in the zip on github there isn't a sln file.

Comment: @AdrianMole do you have any suggestion to overcome this problem?

Comment: Well, not wishing to sound rude, but maybe you should read the VS help and build a project using the source file from the GitHub.

Comment: @AdrianMole it's not rude, it's helpful; I read this in the help "In Solution Explorer, choose or open the project."; my difficulties is to open the project without a sln slnf csproj vbproj shproj exe vcxproj vcproj vcxitems esproj msbuildproj file. Please can you tell me how to open the project?

Comment: @AdrianMole I watched also tutorials; it seems that it's required sln file https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3rm0lxX6Eg&ab_channel=T3SOTutorials

Comment: @AdrianMole I tried also to import directly the repository from github; I'm disperate, nothing works

Comment: @AdrianMole the problem is VS 2019, in VS 2022 there is the build button, but there is only the option "Run code analysis on solution"...strange

Comment: @AdrianMole I download the C++ patches and now also in the 2019 version I have the build button and only the option "run..."

Comment: OK. Try this: Create a simple, "Hello World", Console program using the VS wizard. Then, once that works, just replace the content of the "main.cpp" file with the stuff from the GitHub, But, really, Stack Overflow isn't really the right place for this...

Answer (score 1):

As i see, there is no project in the folder. Only one file hideMe.cpp.
If you double click the file, vs2022 will open it as a file for review. No build option is available.

You can create a project for this folder that contain cpp files and get build menu as follows:

- From File menu -> click New project from Existing code
  A wizard is displayed.
  [image]
- Select Visual c++
- Follow the instruction of the wizard

You will get a project and the build menu will appear